# Batch file to download and run an update, and then email back confirmation

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I've set up a scheduled task to run the follow in a .bat file. It's working beautifully, but now I want it to send me an email containing the install log file. Here's what I have:

> bitsadmin.exe /transfer "Update NXT Beta" /download 1https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/somestuff/setup.exe c:\setup.exe
>
> START C:\setup.exe /autoupdate

setup.exe then exports a log file into its root directory. I want to grab that and email it to myself if I can. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Blat](http://www.blat.net/).

This example would send an email to `my@email.com` (from the same address) using an trusted/relay enabled connection to the local mail server:

```
Blat C:\LogFile.txt -to my@email.com -i my@email.com -subject "Install Completed on %ComputerName%" -server localhost
```

Comment: thanks for this. I've been playing around with it. the smtp server i want to use is returning "can't resolve hostname", but it is certainly valid, as I use it elsewhere w/o authentication. any other suggestions?

Comment: @SkylerJ.Collins - Try using the `-i` switch instead of `-f`. I have updated my answer.